# Check Launch application before server completes startup in WAS via deployment.xml

Tags: deployment, websphere, web-deployment

How can I check this in the deployment.xml in Websphere. So when I deploy my application this is already checked.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the XML attribute is "backgroundApplication" (it's not in there by default, as it defaults to "false"); however, deployment.xml is generated by WebSphere at deployment time, so you can't specify this setting prior to deployment.

If you script your application install through wsadmin, you could update your script to add a call to update the setting after the call to install the app.  That will get the setting modified right away as part of your deployment process.

Comment: I was able to modify the Creat MBeans For Resources by adding this tag in the "createMBeansForResources="false" in the deployment.xml. I tried using this tag "launchApplicationBeforeServerCompletes="true" but still unable to check this. I was wondering if there was a specific tag for that check box.

Comment: Thank you so much. The "backgroundApplication" tag did the trick.